# Find probability in selection

Tags: probability

A bucket has $40$ peaches, $58$ bananas, and $42$ apples.  They are selected in random order with replacement.  Find the probability that at least 4 must be selected in order to get an Apple.

My thinking:

Let $A$ - an event "got an Apple". $B$ - an event "haven't got an Apple".

$\mathbb{P}(A) =\frac{42}{140} = 0.3$, 
$\mathbb{P}(B)=0.7$

$(.7)(.7)(.7)=.343$

Comment: What do you do when you take first a peach. Do you eat it?

Comment: no, with replacement

Comment: Given that this is "with replacement" your method looks good.  But you should edit your question to include the fact that this is with replacement.

Comment: ok, so the .343 means you have 34% of getting an apple?

Comment: @rgentil32 please use MathJax language markup in future

Comment: is there a specific download i should get?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

If we presume that the fruits are not returned after being chosen then we have:
$$P(\text{not apple})=\frac{140-42}{140}=\frac{98}{140}$$
so we have chosen 1 and it is not an apple, now if we repeat this there is one fruit (not an apple) missing so we have:
$$P(\text{2 not apples})=\frac{98}{140}\times\frac{97}{139}$$
$$P(\text{3 not apples})=\frac{98}{140}\times\frac{97}{139}\times\frac{96}{138}$$
$$P(\text{apple on 4th})=\frac{98}{140}\times\frac{97}{139}\times\frac{96}{138}\times\frac{42}{137}$$
So that gives us the probability it takes exactly 4. To calculate at least 4 you want to do this calculation but for:
$$P(n\ge4)=1-\left[P(n=3)+P(n=2)+P(n=1)\right]$$